# Profundizando en el funcionamiento de las colas (queue)

Tags: laravel, queue

Tengo algunas dudas respecto al funcionamiento de las `queues` en laravel, el propósito es evitar procesar una misma tarea simultáneamente, aunque más allá del propósito, seria interesante comprender en su totalidad las respuestas a las siguientes dudas.

> El driver de la queue es database.

1.- ¿Cuál es la forma apropiada de eliminar trabajos (`Job`) duplicados de la cola en base a un atributo en particular de un modelo guardado en el job?

2.- ¿Puede una `queue` ejecutar jobs paralelamente?

Observación: La documentación dice que las `queue` son una pila (FIFO), por lo cual, se entiende que no debería ser el caso. Aunque si enviamos el mismo job a colas con diferentes nombres dentro de nuestra app y ambas se están procesando ¿Puede un job procesarse paralelamente? ¿Algún otro caso de uso similar?

3.- ¿La queue espera a que un job termine completamente antes de ejecutar el siguiente o los va iniciando hasta que eventualmente vayan terminando?

4.- ¿Puedo limitar los recursos del servidor para una queue?

Ej: Máximo 25% ram, máximo 1 núcleo de cpu, etc.

5.- ¿Qué hace realmente la función `WithoutOverlapping`? ¿Qué es lo que previene?

Observación: Si bien laravel lo explica en su documentación, seria interesante una explicación simple con otras palaras u ejemplo.

```
public function middleware() {
        return [(new WithoutOverlapping($this->courseProcessingRequest->course_id))->releaseAfter(60)];
}
```

6.- ¿`WithoutOverlapping` solo funciona para la cola actual o cualquier cola que se esté procesando?